# Move a Subversion server with externals?

Tags: svn

I have just inherited a Subversion server that is a mess. I want to migrate to a new server with a saner file system layout. I figured a `svnadmin dump` and then `svnadmin load` for each repository would be sufficient. However, I have learned the repositories make use of svn externals, and mostly absolute externals. Is it possible to move repositories with externals to a new server?

My current configuration:

```
svn+ssh://subversion.example.com/var/svn/repoA
svn+ssh://subversion.example.com/var/svn/repoB
...
svn+ssh://subversion.example.com/var/svn/repoAA
```

The configuration I want to move to:

```
svn+ssh://vcs.example.com/var/repos/internalDepartmentA/repoA
svn+ssh://vcs.example.com/var/repos/internalDepartmentA/repoB
...
svn+ssh://vcs.example.com/var/repos/internalDepartmentB/repoA
svn+ssh://vcs.example.com/var/repos/internalDepartmentB/repoB
...
svn+ssh://vcs.example.com/var/repos/internalDepartmentC/repoA
svn+ssh://vcs.example.com/var/repos/internalDepartmentC/repoB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I've never tried this.

Externals are just properties, and I'm pretty sure those are dumped as plain text.
Could you try passing your dump file through a perl(or whatever you're comfortable with) script to modify the properties to the new url?

Comment: worth a shot.  If it fails you just get to write a perl script that finds all the externals properties in the tree and does all the substitutions.  Then commit them.

Comment: I was hoping for an easier way, but this looks to be the only option :(

Comment: Just a note, I ended up not doing this at all. Turns out you have to modify checksums when the dump file is being created. It just wasn't worth the effort.